# textbox auto resize on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have a text box resize on click.

in the head:

```
<style>
.expand {
    height: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "1000px" }, 500);
});
</script>
```

and body:

```
<form>
<textarea class="expand" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

it is not expanding for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you haven't specified event-binding on `$(document).ready()`, so the events are bound before the elements exist in the DOM. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: "1000px" }, 500);
    });
});
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/55Ht7/1/).

It's also worth noting that, in the more up-to-date browsers, you don't necessarily require JavaScript for this:

```
.expand {
    height: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -0-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.expand:focus {
    height: 1000px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -0-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/55Ht7/).

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, and it's running properly in JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3d8/1/. You might want to check to make sure that the Google JSAPI is properly pulling jQuery!

Comment: i've tried two different sources for the library, but no luck.

Comment: Ah, David's answer makes sense. JSFiddle auto-wraps Javascript in a DOM ready event, that's why it was working.